# How to find paths for a custom shape from figma file to use in ClipPath Flutter?

Tags: flutter, user-interface, mobile

[image]
I am trying to replicate the plus and minus buttons for product quantity in Flutter,
I want to use ClipPath with child container.
Is there any way to find the path to use for the shape or I have to guess? and Is there any better solution of it instead of Clipping?

```
ClipPath(
        child: Container(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          height: 200,
          color: Colors.red,
        ),
        clipper: CustomClipPath(),
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [flutter shape maker](https://fluttershapemaker.com/) to convert svg to custom path.

```
class CustomPath extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  getClip(Size size) {
    Path path = Path();
    path.lineTo(0, size.height);
    path.cubicTo(...);
    path.cubicTo(...);
    path.cubicTo(...);
    path.cubicTo(...);

    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(covariant CustomClipper oldClipper) {
    return false;
  }
}
```